# Associate custom icon to file extension

Tags: icons, desktop-environments, mime-type, icon-themes

**Problem**: show custom icon for files with *.xyz extension (to be used in deb package)

### Adopted solution

0) Install a fresh ubuntu 19.04 on virtualbox

1) Create a new icon (xyz.svg and xyz.png 48x48)

2) Register a new mime type "text/vnd.xyz": create a xyz.xml file in /usr/share/mime/packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="text/vnd.xyz">
    <comment>XYZ file</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.xyz"/>
    <icon name="xyz"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

3) update mime database with `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`;

4) Create a non empty file test.xyz

5) Check if new mime type has been registered with `mimetype test.xyz` **Result: OK**

6) Copy icons to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/xyz.png` and `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/mimetypes/xyz.svg`

7) Update icon cache with `sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/hicolor` or sudo `gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor`

8) Check in nautilus if test.xyz file has the xyz icon. **Result: Nothing**

### Further experiments

After installed another app ([KeePass 2](https://packages.debian.org/it/sid/keepass2)) I tried with the follow:

a) alter the xyz.xml file in order to use an already registered icon like "image-svg+xml". **Result: it works**

b) alter the xyz.xml file in order to use an application registered icon like "application-x-keepassx". **Result: it doesn't work**

c) alter the keepassx.xml file in order to use xyz icon. **Result: it works! .kdbx files have xyz icon!**

"image-svg+xml" is located in the Yaru theme while "application-x-keepassx" is in hicolor: it seems that I have some problem to get icons from hicolor but keepass uses them with no problem.

Any suggestion?